# Brokered components when using TFS Build

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

When using TFS to build my application, it fails when I have an application with Brokered components.

Here is what I am using in my Package.appxmanifest, and it works when I build/run locally. How can I still build/deploy using TFS and keep my brokered components? Is this possible?

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="BrokeredRuntimeComponent.{ClassName}" ThreadingModel="MTA">
          <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath"
                                     Type="string"
                                     Value="C:\Source\{AppName}\Debug\BrokeredRuntimeComponentProxy" />
        </ActivatableClass>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

When I run the build, I get the following error. I do not have access to run the `regsvr32 /s` on our TFS. Is this something that needs to be done on every client or can it be done on the build server and run on every device? I think it might work if it's possible to get the build service to run as administrator. Is this even possible?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (1620): Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.
```

Please let me know if anything I've put here is unclear so I can hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have everything installed on your build server that your need to run a build locally. If you need certain registered components then that needs done in advance or at build time.

If at build time then the account that TF build runs under needs permission to perform that action.

Comment: I had to change the Linker on my proxy project to no longer Register Output in order for the build to run. It has a script post-build that will register it. I had to make sure that my account running the build is an admin